# Growl style without a fade or animation

Tags: notifications, growl

I would like to use Growl to show feedback of the input from a Griffin PowerMate (I'm doing this with AppleScript). High Sierra's built-in notifications can't keep up with the rate of input of the PowerMate. Growl's notifications can keep up but only by spreading out notifications over the space of the screen, which is hard for the eye to follow. Growl's "Bezel" style is an example of a style that stays put, but it has animations that slow it down. Growl styles programed in Cocoa can have their own fades or animations, so it should be possible to use Cocoa to make a style that has no fade at all, or a very short fade. I don't have time to look through hundreds of Growl styles, but perhaps someone already knows of such a style?

relevant link - http://growl.info

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that Quicksilver has its own notification system which the user can activate by going to Quicksilver > Preferences > Handlers. Quicksilver's notifications can be triggered by AppleScript:

```
tell application "Quicksilver"
    show notification "notification text"
end tell
```

These notifications can refresh quickly and they stay put, which is what I was looking for.